# Use finditem() only on one Column

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I have a QTableWidget populated with QtableWidgetItems.

I want a searchbar, where I can type in and as Response the Table should be refreshing and only showing the items that match partially with the string in the search field.

Im using finditem for that, but i want that only one column is used for the search. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate the table manually.

```
columnOfInterest = 1 # or whatever
valueOfInterest = "foo" 
for rowIndex in range(self.myTable.rowCount()):
    twItem = self.myTable.item(rowIndex, columnOfInterest)
    if twItem.text() == valueOfInterest:
        self.myTable.setRowHidden(rowIndex, False)
    else:
        self.myTable.setRowHidden(rowIndex, True)
```

You will have to implement better matching criteria. You can use string functions like [`str.find` and `str.startswith` and others](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) if you want to do it yourself.

Comment: Very nice idea to use `setRowHidden` for "refreshing", thank you for that!